# Assign Javascript variable value to Ampscript

Tags: javascript, ampscript, cookies

I am using code below to get cookie and assign it to ampscript variable @user

```
function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("email");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Checking cookie: " + user);
        Variable.SetValue("@user", user);
    } else {

    }
}
```

I am calling check cookie function on body on load:

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
```

I am using code below to display different content based on whether cookie is present or not.

```
%%[IF EMPTY(@user) THEN]%%

%%[ELSE]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

I am able to set cookie, get cookie and check cookie. Check cookie alert displays correct information. However, the value of cookie is not getting assigned to @user by 
`Variable.SetValue("@user", user);`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, another way of doing this is to use ampscript to grab and store the value of the cookie.

So something like this. This will parse out the value out of the cookie.

```
%%[

set @cookieName = 'cookieName' 
set @subject = HTTPRequestHeader("Cookie")
set @pattern = Concat(@cookieName, '=(.*?)(;\s|$)') 
set @cookieValue = RegExMatch(@subject, @pattern, 1) 
set @user = @cookieValue 

IF EMPTY(@user) THEN]%%

%%[ELSE]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix [server-side JavaScript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) and client-side JavaScript.  Think of SSJS as you would PHP.